# GLSDK - Can't execute example OpenGL program

Tags: c++, opengl, windows-8.1

I am in the process of checking my OpenGL install works fine, but my example program crashes at **execution** (with no real error message hint). I am using the unofficial **GLSDK** (http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html) distribution and compiled it under windows 8.

The program (http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/)

```
#include <glload/gl_3_2_comp.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>


void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void display(void);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutCreateWindow("GLUT Test");
  glutKeyboardFunc(&keyboard);
  glutDisplayFunc(&display);
  glutMainLoop();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
  switch (key)
  {
    case '\x1B':
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      break;
  }
}


void display()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex2f( 0.5f,  0.5f);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f,  0.5f);
  glEnd();

  glFlush();
}
```

I know that `#include <glload/gl_3_2_comp.h>` is the culprit here because if I change this line to `#include <GL/gl.h>` then the example program runs fine and displays a nice red square on a black background... Alternatively if I remove the contents of the `display()` function the program runs fine too.

Problem is : I need to use OpenGL 3.x or above API so I can't just include the OS header who is ridiculously outdated (Windows 8).

My Linker settings (in Code::Blocks) :

- glloadD
- glimgD
- glutilD
- glmeshD
- freeglutD
- glu32
- opengl32
- gdi32
- winmm
- user32

With include paths :

- glsdk\glload\lib
- glsdk\glimg\lib
- glsdk\glutil\lib
- glsdk\glmesh\lib
- glsdk\freeglut\lib

And #Defines :

- FREEGLUT_STATIC
- _LIB
- FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [GL Load documentation](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/group__module__glload.html), it looks like you need to explicitly initialize it:

```
#include <glload/gl_load.h>
...
ogl_LoadFunctions();
```

where the `ogl_LoadFunctions()` call needs to be after you set up GLUT.

Comment: Thanks. I must admit I didn't pay attention to this manual entry. I'm glad you pointed it out! Will check asap.